# Django rest framework browsable api root url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I love DRF but I still find its documentation really frustrating, for real, a lot of advanced tips and examples are there but I still always dive into toughness and frustration when I'm looking for the most basic stuff of any topic of the amazing framework.

In this case, [this resource](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/)
looks really cool! But they don't even start by how to make it work (or what could not be properly configured if it isn't working as in my case). Could someone tell me what's the holy api root URL or how to include/configure it? Because I don't see it in my URLs and so far I didn't find anything in the official docs.

***I also followed the quickstart tutorial.***

This is what I have:

[image]

My main urls.py:

```
api_urls = [
    path('rest_framework/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('', include('project.posts.urls')),
    path('', include('project.users.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(api_urls)),
]
```

users.urls:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

posts.urls:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet, basename='posts')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I can log in into the DRF panel but then I get a redirection error.

[image]

Also I can see the pages if I manually go to a valid endpoint URL, but it's not an actual navigation from the root point of the API.

Comment: `drf-yasg` is a great package for creating a Swagger UI for your APIs https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#quickstart

Comment: You are hitting the wrong URL, /accout/profile/ is not available.
Error is showing that you can use either /admin/ or /api/ after base url ( localhost:8000)

Comment: yes @Somil I can see that, but that's the framework redirection itself after a successful login request...